# Use a drop down list to select feed using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have looked around for a good minute and cannot find out how to get the intended results.
The goal: From the drop down list, select one of the options, Headlines, NFL, NCAA, or MLB.
Upon doing so display the corresponding feed.
My current method of doing this is to attempt to change the DataFile attribute by refreshing the page upon selecting a drop down list item.
This is not necessarily how it has to be done, but that's the rout I couldn't get to work.

Any advice or pointers would be great, except to any microsoft related pages on account that their service monopoly more or less prevents them from being helpful, especially when I don't have to fork over money.... 
Here is the code:
(and a note that I don't intend to publish any of this, apparently some consider linking to RSS feeds like i'm trying to 'stealing.' Just a class assignment in this case).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="true">

            <asp:ListItem>Headlines</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>NFL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>NCAA Football</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>MLB</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <a href="<%#XPath("link") %>"> <%#XPath("title") %></a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/headlines" 
            XPath="rss/channel/item">
        </asp:XmlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FeedSource = XmlDataSource1.DataFile;;
        string FeedName = "";

        switch (FeedName)
        {
            case "HHeadlines":
                FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/headlines";
                break;
            case "NFL":
                FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/nfl";
                break;
            case "NCAA Football":
                FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/cfb";
                break;
            case "MLB":
                FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/mlb";
                break;

        }
    }
    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "except to any microsoft related pages" that's going to be tricky, given they wrote asp.net & host all the reference material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the selected value from dropdownlist and change the XmlDataSource1.DataFile accordingly. Then rebind the listview1:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FeedSource = XmlDataSource1.DataFile; ;
    string FeedName = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;

    switch (FeedName)
    {
        case "HHeadlines":
            FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/headlines";
            break;
        case "NFL":
            FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/nfl";
            break;
        case "NCAA Football":
            FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/cfb";
            break;
        case "MLB":
            FeedSource = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxsports/rss/mlb";
            break;

    }
    XmlDataSource1.DataFile = FeedSource;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

[Scott Mitchell](http://scottonwriting.net/ScottMitchell.asp) wrote many very helpful articles about rss, one [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043745/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031903-1.aspx), [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478968.aspx) another one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works exactly as I need it to! Thank you greatly. I however, cannot say I completely understand. Why re-declared the FeedSource variable outside of the switch? (My guess is the switch changed it and then the re-declaration inserts it).
I also have no knowledge of the DataBind method.
But again, thanks a lot for the answer and reading materials, wonderful!

Comment: You were assigning the datafile property to a variable, which is one way and the xmldatasource doesn't know anything about any change unless you tell it like ` XmlDataSource1.DataFile = FeedSource;`. And rebinding is to tell the listview to get fresh data from the xmldatasource instead of using stale data from viewstate. Hope it makes sense!